# Journey Builder Wait Period Dates

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, filters

I can't seem to find any documentation on whether wait periods of days are based on calendar date or full 24 hour periods of time. If I have a scenario where after entry I have a wait period of 2 days and then hours associated to a local time zone are the days of the wait period evaluated based on calendar day of entry or will the wait period be a full 48hrs after the entry date based on time of entry? Trying to determine if entries injected on, say, a Friday afternoon would be evaluated on Sunday to proceed if the hour was set to proceed in the morning or if they would not move forward until Monday morning based on being inserted on Friday afternoon.

Comment: I'm unsure, so not an answer, but I believe it a 24 hour wait, or 2 day wait, will wait exactly that many hours. Because there's a "wait until" feature which wouldn't make sense to have otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 24 hour wait, so you can control at what time the next activity will execute. Assume we have an email activity after wait, you wouldn't want to send out email at 12 midnight, hence the implementation is to wait for 24 hours per day of wait time. Hope this helps!